# How to control mp3 audio volume using JMF in JAVA

Tags: java, jmf

I am using JMF for playing mp3 Audio file.It is playing but I have no idea how to control its volume? I am using

```
Player audioPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
audioPlayer.start();
```

Comment: against which environment are you developing?

Answer (score 1):

See [`Player.getGainControl()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Player.html#getGainControl()) which:

> Gets the object for controlling this `Playe`r's audio gain. If this player does not have a `GainControl`, `getGainControl` returns `null`. For example, `getGainControl` might return `null` if the `Player` does not play audio data.

On [`GainControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/GainControl.html):

> `GainControl` is an interface for manipulating audio signal gain.
>
> ### Gain and Gain Measures
>
> Gain is a multiplicative value applied to an audio signal that modifies the **amplitude of the signal.** This interface allows the gain to be specified in either decibels or using a floating point value that varies between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on Android in this fashion.

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        final int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);



        SeekBar volumecontrol = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        volumecontrol.setMax(maxVolume);
        volumecontrol.setProgress(curVolume);
        volumecontrol.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromuser) {

                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress, 0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Arsalan but i need in JAVA using JMF

Comment: even though implemented on a different system the approach from @ArsalanHussain is the proper way to do it - the volume is changed by the volume manager, whatever system you are using!